# Creating onBeforeCreate dynamic hook using SQL language

Tags: orientdb

I want to create a dynamic hook for the onBeforeCreate event using SQL to validate a record. How do you access the properties of the new record within the function?

I'm using OrientDB 3.0.4. From the studio, I enter these commands into a new database to set it up:

```
create class Kid extends V,OTriggered;
create property Kid.FirstName String;
create property Kid.LastName String;
create property Kid.Age Integer;
create property Kid.Grade Integer;
create function CreatingKid 'begin; console.log "Creating Kid"; commit; return "ok";' language SQL;
alter class Kid custom onBeforeCreate=CreatingKid;
```

I use the following to test it out and it doesn't seem to work. Nothing gets printed in the log:

```
insert into Kid(FirstName, LastName, Age, Grade)values('Karen', 'Tooyoung', 8, 10);
```

I have two questions: 1) how do I know if the CreatingKid function is being called (I'm not seeing the "Creating Kid" message in the console), and 2) how should I change the CreatingKid function to compare the age and grade and reject the record if the age minus grade is less than 5?

Comment: kindly consider adding more information, the code you attempted for your problem, otherwise this question will be removed

Comment: Hi, did you already took a look at this? https://orientdb.com/docs/3.0.x/internals/Dynamic-Hooks.html Hope it helps

Comment: @michela:  It does not show how to access the document's properties within an SQL function.  It shows Javascript.